# Increment column i element by values inside list

Tags: python, list, increment

I have a loop that searches keywords in a text file and pastes integers that follow the keywords into an excel file. I want the integers to be in specific cells in the excel file. Is it possible to increment i by the values in i_list rather than always 5 like in the example?

```
i_list = [5,3,1,1]

def search(file, excel_file):
    i = 2
    found_keywords = list()
    wb = load_workbook(excel_file)
    sheets = wb.sheetnames
    sheet1 = wb[sheets[0]]

    for kwrd in keywords:
        for line in file:
            if kwrd in line and kwrd not in found_keywords:
                found_keywords.append(kwrd)
                sheet1.cell(row=3, column=i).value = int(re.search(r"\d+", line).group())
                i += 5
            elif kwrd in line:
                continue

    wb.save(excel_file)
```

Comment: Do you need to cycle round the values of `i` I.E once you use all the values are  you expecting to go back to the start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont need to cycle through the values of i then you can just create a generator to return you the values of `i` one by one. I have wrapped the calling of the next value of `i` in a try block since once you run out of values the code wouldnt know what to do. so we break the loop

```py
i_list = (i for i in [5,3,1,1])
i = 2
for _ in range(10):
    print(i)
    try:
        i += next(i_list)
    except StopIteration as si:
        print("no more values in i so loop terminating")
        break
```

**OUTPUT**

```
2
7
10
11
12
no more values in i so loop terminating
```

However if you want to cycle thorugh the values of i you can use cycle from itertools module and infintly take the next item from i_list for as long as you need

```py
from itertools import cycle
i_list = cycle([5,3,1,1])
i = 2
for _ in range(10):
    print(i)
    i += next(i_list)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
2
7
10
11
12
17
20
21
22
27
```

**UPDATE OF YOUR CODE**

below is an update of your code based on the fact you said you dont have to cycle. Remember that once you reach the end of i_list your code will not be able to increase i since there are no more values in i_list.

```py
i_list = [5,3,1,1]
i_generator = (i for i in i_list)

def search(file, excel_file):
    i = 2
    found_keywords = list()
    wb = load_workbook(excel_file)
    sheets = wb.sheetnames
    sheet1 = wb[sheets[0]]

    for kwrd in keywords:
        for line in file:
            if kwrd in line and kwrd not in found_keywords:
                found_keywords.append(kwrd)
                sheet1.cell(row=3, column=i).value = int(re.search(r"\d+", line).group())
                i += next(i_generator)
            elif kwrd in line:
                continue

    wb.save(excel_file)
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about the next function

Comment: @Wessowang I have updated my answer based on your comment that you dont need to cycle i. so it makes a generator from i_list and then when you increase i you do it by giving the next item from the generator. As i said though this will only work until you run out of items in the generator

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet, adjusted from the original, cycles through the values of `i_list`:

```
i_list = [5,3,1,1]

def search(file, excel_file):
    i = 2
    found_keywords = list()
    wb = load_workbook(excel_file)
    sheets = wb.sheetnames
    sheet1 = wb[sheets[0]]

    for kwrd in keywords:
        for line in file:
            if kwrd in line and kwrd not in found_keywords:
                for i in i_list: # Update i based on the i-list value
                    sheet1.cell(row=3, column=i).value = int(re.search(r"\d+", line).group())
            elif kwrd in line:
                continue
    wb.save(excel_file)
```

Comment: @Wessowang Tell me, if it works, or if I should change it.

Comment: This will perform the `if kwrd` code for n number of times per line where n is the length of i_list. I think the OP only wants to execute the if code once per line and each time the condition is met and the sheet is update, then change the value of i. Not change the value of i and run the same line multiple times. The value of i should only be changed after sheet1.cell is called then it should go on to the next line

Comment: @ChrisDoyle Sorry I just understand what you've meant, I updated the code.
Thanks for helping me, to improve my answer.

Comment: Your code is still going to update the value in multiple cells.........when the if is true only one cell should be updated, then i should be set to the next num and the code should move on to the next line. your code will see the if condition true then update that value for all the values in i_list. again thats not what the OP wants. He wants, if value true update cell then move i to the next value and move to the next line.

Comment: In the OP code, when the if is true only one cell is updated, and the value of i is increased once. in your code if the if is true then you will update the value of i 4 times and update the cells 4 times

Comment: @ChrisDoyle Maybe I didn't understand, his unclear requirements exactly. However, he will try both answers, and pick the most appropriate one.

Comment: @ChrisDoyle let's just wait in a few hours, he is probably going to accept and upvote yours.

Comment: like i say it doesnt bother me whos is up voted or accepted, am not hear to gain rep, i am just here to help people, both people answering questions and people posting answers, I am not trying to discredit your answer or tyring to criticise you personally. please dont take it that way.

Comment: @ChrisDoyle I know you are trying to help, but with no feedback from the OP at all, I  think there is no point in further changing both of our answers.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. As @ChrisDoyle says I want the first integer to be in column 2, the second in column 7, the third in column 10 and so on